# can we add if / else statement in Javascript's / jQuery "innerhtml"

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JS :**

```
   var overlayContainer = 
    '<div class="customerOverlayShadow">'+
        '<div class="customerOverlay">'+

            '<span class="customerCloseIcon" title="close"></span>'+
            '<div class="custWhtBg">'+
                '<h2 class="customerPopHeading">Government Account Validation</h2>'+
                '<div class="custGreytBg clearfix">'+


// here it starts 
                    if(customerInfo="changeCustomer"){
                        '<p class="custTxtUnknown">YoYo  </p>'+
                        '<p class="custTxtProcees">Would you like to proceed with using account 248578</p>'+
                    }
                    else{
                        '<p class="custTxtUnknown">NO NO </p>'+
                        '<p class="custTxtProcees">Would you like to proceed with using account 248578</p>'+
                    }




                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>';
     console.log(overlayContainer)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
    var overlayContainer = 
        '<div class="customerOverlayShadow">'+
            '<div class="customerOverlay">'+

                '<span class="customerCloseIcon" title="close"></span>'+
                '<div class="custWhtBg">'+
                    '<h2 class="customerPopHeading">Government Account Validation</h2>'+
                    '<div class="custGreytBg clearfix">';
     // here it starts 
                        if(customerInfo == "changeCustomer") {
                           overlayContainer += '<p class="custTxtUnknown">YoYo </p>'+
                            '<p class="custTxtProcees">Would you like to proceed with using account 248578</p>';
                        }
                        else {
                            overlayContainer += '<p class="custTxtUnknown">NO NO </p>'+
                            '<p class="custTxtProcees">Would you like to proceed with using account 248578</p>';
                        }




  overlayContainer +='</div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>';
         console.log(overlayContainer)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on one long string concatenation, you'll have to use the [Ternary Operator (?:)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

```
"some_long_string" +

(customerInfo == "changeCustomer" ?
     '<p class="custTxtUnknown">YoYo</p>...' :
     '<p class="custTxtUnknown">NO NO </p>...') + 

"another_long_string"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But here you using assignment operator inside if condition. "=" is assignment operator. For comparison Use "==". So th condition will be now

```
if(customerInfo=="changeCustomer")
```